# Updating a valve assembly: can a PVB have multiple downstream valves?

Tags: plumbing

So I have this hose bib setup in my backyard that the pool company setup. It consists of a hose bib and then an ABV teeing off from that and feeding into two quarter-turn valves. One valve feeds an automated water-leveler for my pool, and the other feeds all of my irrigation valves. I'm looking to replace this masterpiece due to the fact that the PVC quarter-turn valves are already leaking and because I'm pretty sure this setup is not to code. I had a few questions to help drive some of my decisions going forward, and some just out of curiosity.

1. It's my understanding that there should be zero downstream valves from an ABV, be them manual or automatic. Is that correct? Is it valid to have a valve between the ABV and the leveler? I'm pretty sure I'm supposed to have ABVs *after* EACH of my irrigation valves if I'm using ABVs.
2. The plumber insisted that there be a hose bib by the ABV, and I've definitely seen this type of setup before. But is that actually a requirement? I can find nothing anywhere stating as much, and I've seen setups without hose bibs.
3. My current plan is to replace this whole setup with copper and use a PVB. with a PVB, it is permitted to have downstream valves, correct? So I can have one PVB feeding my whole system? And I don't need a hose bib in that setup do I? There's one literally 3 feet away and this one seems redundant.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I am not sure why they said a hose bib was required, it could be a local requirement I know in some areas they are required to be tested every 3 years when connected to city water systems.